# How to define a pointer on a array of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, declaration, string-literals

Can someone explain how i can define this array of strings?

[image]

`a` is a pointer and its points to a array of chars. So it has to be `char *a[3]`?

Comment: Show all relevant code in your question instead of providing links.

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want an array of pointers or a pointer to an array?

Comment: I'd be careful here. The picture suggests `a` is *not* an array; it's a pointer. The smidgeon of `b` we see in this picture suggests named arrays have a different pictorial vernacular. Therefore, I'd suggest `char *a[3]` is not necessarily what the assignment is calling for. May want to get clarification from whatever human resource doled this thing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is defined as an array of pointers to string literals like

```
char * a[3] = { "A", "B", "C" };
```

where instead of "A", "B", "C" you can use your own string literals.

To declare a pointer to the first element of such an array you can write

```
char **p = a;
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char * a[] = { "A", "B", "C" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    char **p = a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", p[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* a[3];
a[0]="Datentypen";
a[1] = "und";
a[2] = "Variablen";
```